# mysql group by to show same content from mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have one table where one column name is city. for every user i can display how many number of users are there from that city (from which user belongs) but i want to display who all are . so i have tried this mysql query but it is not working

```
$res = sql_query("select *  from ".tb()."data  where city='{$owner['city']}' group by city order by fullname  limit 10 "  );
```

if any one is having any idea please advice how to solve.the main work is to show all users from that city suppose if user A belongs to Tokyo so when someone will click on that link which shows how many numbers are there from Tokyo it should show all users from that country .other part i have done and i am able to display also but it displays all results .

Comment: Do you want the total number of user in a specifiq city? Then why you use `GROUP BY` in city_name, it will return you only one row.

Comment: yes i want to display total number of users. suppose if from tokyo 100 are there then it should display all 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `group by` from the request:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE city='Tokyo' ORDER BY fullname;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments just use the following query :

```
$res = sql_query("select *  from ".tb()."data  where city='{$owner['city']}' order by fullname "  );
```

Comment: frustrated i tried this also but it is displaying all results of different cities also.i want to filter city

Comment: How does it display different city's info? `WHERE city = 'Tokyo'` filter all result. can you give the table structure and data sample?